# Пересоздание Bean в Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Есть некий `Bean`, который создаётся автоматически с параметрами по умолчанию. Можно ли этот `Bean` создать заново с другими параметрами в процессе работы программы?

P.S. Разработчики к сожалению не предусмотрели get/set для изменения этих параметров. Иначе решение вопроса было бы очевидными.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению не знаю деталей вашей задачи, но возможно поможет указать [Scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) ?
Например:

```
<bean id="accountService" class="com.foo.DefaultAccountService" scope="prototype"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Почитал документацию, книги...

В общем, пересоздать `Bean` заново вручную не получится, т.к. его жизненным циклом и регистрацией в Spring управляет DI-контейнер.

Остаётся только либо прописывать `scope`(если это соответствует задаче), либо использовать обычные Java объекты.

Как-то так...

Comment: если бы Вы подробнее описали проблему, было бы проще